# Checking a palindrome in python using stack

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack, palindrome

I want to check whether a certain word is a palindrome or not. This is the python code I wrote to check. But it's not giving me the correct result.

Stack Class

```
class Stack:
def __init__(self):
    self.items=[]

def isEmpty(self):
    return self.items==[]

def push(self,data):
    self.items.append(data)

def size(self):
    return len(Self.items)

def show(self):
    print (self.items)

def peek(self):
    return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

def pop(self):
    assert not self.isEmpty()
    return self.items.pop()
```

The program

```
a=input("Enter a word: ")
s=Stack();

for i in a:
    s.push(i);

while s is None:
    list1 = s.pop();

if(list1 == a):
    print("The word is a palindrome");
else:
    print("It's not a palindrome");
    print(a);
    print(list1);
```

I'm getting this error.

```
 RESTART: C:/Users/Dil/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Tutorials/checkpalindrome.py 
Enter a word: kayak
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dil/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Tutorials/checkpalindrome.py", line 35, in <module>
    if(list1 == a):
NameError: name 'list1' is not defined
```

But if I changed my program to the following:

```
a= input("Enter a word: ")

s=Stack();

for i in a:
    s.push(i);
    list1 = s.pop();

if(list1 == a):
    print("The word is a palindrome");
else:
    print("It's not a palindrome");
    print(a);
    print(list1);
```

It will give me the output as follows:

```
>>> 
 RESTART: C:/Users/Dil/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Tutorials/checkpalindrome.py 
Enter a word: kayak
It's not a palindrome
kayak
k
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output at the end of your question makes it pretty clear why this is happening.  `a` contains the string `kayak`, while `list1` contains a single letter: `k`.  This is because the line `list1 = s.pop()` reassigns `list1` to a single letter each time it is called.  You need to append to `list1` instead of overwriting it.  As Phydeaux notes, the proper way to do this is to define `list1` before the loop as an empty string like so: `list1 = ""`.  And then in the loop, append to it like so: `list1 += s.pop()`.

However, there's another issue, namely that having `s.push(i)` and `list1 += s.pop()` in the same loop will copy the string in order, rather than in reverse order.  This is because you are adding a single item to your stack and immediately emptying it on every loop iteration.  What you should do is make your calls to `s.push()` in one loop, and then the `list1 += s.pop()` calls in a second loop to get the reversed string.

Try this out:

```
for i in a:
  s.push(i)

list1 = ""
while not s.isEmpty():
  list1 += s.pop()
```

As a side note: python doesn't require semicolons at the end of a line.  I realize you're likely going through a tutorial for data structures, but a pythonic way to check for a palindrome would be `return a == a[::-1]`.